# couldn't find "libjniavutil.so" in my android studio

Tags: android, ffmpeg

While initializing FFmpegFrameRecorder I'm getting crash in android PIE(9.0) and marshmallow as well.

Below I mentioned where exactly I'm getting a crash and logCat as well of a crash.

Can any one of you please help me to sort it out.?

```
  mVideo = CameraUtil.getOutputMediaFile(recordedTime, CameraUtil.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Output Video: " + mVideo);
    mFrameRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(mVideo, videoWidth, videoHeight, 1);
    mFrameRecorder.setFormat("mp4");
    mFrameRecorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
    mFrameRecorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
    mFrameRecorder.setGopSize(60);
```

Here I mentioned my LogCat File

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1694)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:152)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:132)
    at com.starcam.test1.activities.EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.initRecorder(EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.java:606)
    at com.starcam.test1.activities.EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.access$800(EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.java:83)
    at com.starcam.test1.activities.EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion$9.doInBackground(EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.java:458)
    at com.starcam.test1.activities.EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion$9.doInBackground(EventLiveFrame3VideoQuestion.java:453)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.starcam.test1-Tndkf7jqvwcCdq5w3dj8CQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.starcam.test1-Tndkf7jqvwcCdq5w3dj8CQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.starcam.test1-Tndkf7jqvwcCdq5w3dj8CQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjniavutil.so"
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If yes can you please help out?